Trying to get the index of a row that whose matches with another element
I'm trying to get the Index (As a integral) of a specific raw on my df, my df is multi index as I've concatenated two dataframes (Date dataframe and Price dataframe)
dataframe = pd.concat([date_df, prices_df], axis='columns')

It looks similar to this
 Date      Price

index                    0     0.0000
0      2024-04-30 10:21:43  3333.3625
1      2024-04-30 10:23:43  3288.2678
2      2024-04-30 10:25:43  3293.0690
3      2024-04-30 10:27:43  3280.0830
4      2024-04-30 10:29:43  3273.8162
5      2024-04-30 10:31:43  3268.4622
6      2024-04-30 10:33:43  3262.4119
7      2024-04-30 10:35:43  3256.7690
8      2024-04-30 10:37:43  3252.1814

Also, what I'm trying to do is update it with a now object (That needs to be a string for pd.query)
now = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0, second=7)
now = str(now)
print(now)

> 2024-04-30 12:21:07

So I have some options, I've tried pd.query() like:
row_index = dataframe.query(dataframe['Date'] == str(now)).index[0]

Got:

row_index = dataframe.query(dataframe['Date'] == str(now)).index\[0]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\\Users\\Angel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\frame.py", line 4437, in query
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, \<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'\> given

Tried dataframe.index() like:
row_index = dataframe.index[dataframe['Date'] == str(now)].tolist()

Got:
[]

Tried dataframe.index.get_loc() like:
row_index = data.index.get_loc(dataframe['Date'] == now)

Got:
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: index    False
0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
...
43196    False
43197    False
43198    False
43199    False
43200    False
Name: Date, Length: 43202, dtype: bool
Index: []


OR
row_index = dataframe.index.get_loc(dataframe.loc[data.iloc[:, 0] == str(now)])

Got:
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Price]
Index: []

It says the dataframe is empty
I've tried to resolve it coding an ecxeption with:
from pandas.errors import EmptyDataError
try:


    if dataframe.empty:
        raise EmptyDataError

except EmptyDataError:
print('dataframe is empty')

I just want to get the index as an integer of the now string whose match with the date row in my dataframe
If there's anyone that could give feedback and knows better how to resolve it, I really appreciate the help.your text
Expected Output:
>5980 

For example

Welcome to SO! [MRE]: First it is not clear if you have a multi index, looking at the input dataframe. Could you clarify that? Then please post an expected outout, unless I have missed that. Finally please add tag [python]. You may probably remove tags variable and integer, as they are little informative about your question.

datetime portion of the question aside, have you been through this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/12846804

You need to make sure that the Date column in the DataFrame is of type datetime with pd.to_datetime().
Then, the use of strftime helps ensuring the query format is aligned with datetime.
Finally, boolean indexing should work the way you intend it to.
data_dict = {'Date': ['2024-04-30 10:21:43', '2024-04-30 10:23:43'], 'Price': [3333.3625, 3288.2678]}
dataframe= pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
dataframe['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['Date'])

now = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0, second=7) 
now_str = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

index_list = dataframe.index[dataframe['Date'] == now_str].tolist()

